# How can I get VS for Mac to recognize that I have .NET Core 5.06 SDK installed? I may have installed the binaries wrong

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, command-line, executable, visual-studio-mac

I've been trying to work with Xamarin on VS for Mac but when I try to build something it throws this error:
`Error: .NET Core 5.06 SDK is required to build this application, and is not installed. Install the latest update to the .NET Core 5.06 SDK by visiting https://aka.ms/vs/mac/install-netcore56`

And this appears at the top of the screen:
[image]

First of all, the link is broken. Second, I checked and I've already got the newest version of everything else installed so I looked here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0 and found that there's just a binary download for .NET Core 5.06 for mac, no installer.

I don't have any experience with binaries so I did some googling and found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos#download-and-manually-install
Which said to run this in the terminal:

```
DOTNET_FILE=aspnetcore-runtime-5.0.6-osx-x64.tar.gz
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet

mkdir -p "$DOTNET_ROOT" && tar zxf "$DOTNET_FILE" -C "$DOTNET_ROOT"

export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT
```

I made a few mistakes when I did it the first time and it threw some errors but I fixed them and when I ran it the last time nothing popped up so I figure it worked. Anyway, That didn't fix it. VS still says I don't have that version installed.
`dotnet --list-runtimes` gives me this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

And listing sdks gives me this:

```
3.1.409 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

This looks right to me but if that's the case then VS is the problem and it's not recognizing my installed versions. Anyway, I'm a little stuck now. I haven't found a whole lot of stuff at my level when it comes to doing this. Hoping someone can help!

Comment: From the download page, the Asp.net core v5.0.6 is included in Visual Studio 2019 16.10 version, you could refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/update?view=vsmac-2019) to update the VS version. Besides, try to download the Installer from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/5.0/5.0.6/5.0.6.md).

Comment: What target framework is in your csproj file? The error message suggests to me that you have set the target framework in the project to be net5.06 which is not correct it should be net50 here.

Comment: Also using `export PATH` from a bash or zsh terminal has no affect on Visual Studio for Mac unless you run Visual Studio for Mac from that same terminal window.

Comment: Ok tried to reproduce what you are seeing. The only way I can do that is to create a global.json file for the solution (close and re-open the solution) with the global.json file specifying the sdk as 5.06. There is no such sdk version - sdk versions are 5.0.100 and later. A simple fix here would be to remove the global.json file and close and re-open the solution. Or specify the sdk version you have installed (which would be 5.0.300 for you). Also worth checking the sdk versions in VS Mac's about dialog page to ensure it has the ones you have installed. Sdks are cached for the ide session.

Comment: Turns out I had a global.json in one of my projects that was changing it for all of them for some reason. I just deleted it and it worked!