# Visual Studio for Mac doesn't recognise .Net 5

Tags: visual-studio, .net-5, apple-m1

I have just installed an update for Visual Studio for Mac. Unfortunately the IDE cannot find .Net5 now! Please see the screenshot. I uninstalled .Net5 and reinstalled, installed .Net 6 and also tried restarting my MacBook Pro but none of them worked. I tried using the global.json file, checked my local paths etc. again none of them worked. How am I going to fix this issue? Any suggestions?

Also, I googled and found similar questions in StackOverFlow but again none of the solutions worked for me:

[How can I get VS for Mac to recognize that I have .NET Core 5.06 SDK installed? I may have installed the binaries wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67808826/how-can-i-get-vs-for-mac-to-recognize-that-i-have-net-core-5-06-sdk-installed)
[Visual Studio for Mac is failing to find .Net 6.0 or .Net 5.0 on upgrading to VS Mac 8.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934039/visual-studio-for-mac-is-failing-to-find-net-6-0-or-net-5-0-on-upgrading-to-vs)

When I enter ***dotnet --version*** the terminal shows "5.0.207"

[image: My Visual Studio for Mac 8.10.19 (build 2)]

Answer (score 0):

After digging Google and stackoverflow for around 12 hours, finally I found the reason of this .NET 5 framework error!

In Mac M1, go to: **/usr/local/bin** and delete the **dotnet** shortcut:

[image]

After deleting this file, close the Visual Studio and open it again. Compile your project and no errors!

Comment: version 5 , It does not appear on my mac